# Creating laptop wifi hotspot losing ssid when sharing connection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop, hotspot

I have created a wifi hotspot on my work laptop I started the hostednetwork and in the network and sharing page I could see the ssid 'hotSpot1' under the wireless network connection 2 (WNC2) icon. I also could see the ssid in the currently connected to part of the available networks page when selecting the bottom right hand corner bars. i.e.

currently connected to:

workcompany.com 
internet access

hotspot1
No internet access

However when I share the wireless network connection (WNC) that the workcompany.com is connected to with hotspot1. The ssid is changed to workcompany.com. so both WNC and WNC2 ssid's are displaying workcompany.com.

I have also lost the ssid in the 'currently connected to' section  as well it now displays:

currently connected to:

workcompany.com 
internet access

When I look for hotspot1 from my mobile device I cannot find it.
Anybody got any clues. Please help.

p.s. the workcompany.com internet is a domain (if it helps)

Comment: do you have two wireless network adapters? can you provide us your laptop model?